# problem with start and execute a docker container

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-jetson

I am new to docker
I am using ssh to connect to Nvidia jetson NX and use the docker on nvidia
the system for nvidia is a modifed ubuntu 18.04 called tegra.

What I want to do is to exec the container named tetraai_service_nx.
It worked fine until yesterday by command "docker exec -it tetraai_service_nx /bin/bash
"
however, today when I tried the same command, i see"Error response from daemon: Container 0feeb9be5a251bb9ce45ed9a05d24a86e5a77ef9d93439c717fdef9f7a6560d4 is not running
"
0feeb9be5a251bb9ce45ed9a05d24a86e5a77ef9d93439c717fdef9f7a6560d4 is the right id for the container I want which is correct.

Then i tried as in the following picture and got the error

[This is the error i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jxFm.png)
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container tetraai_service_nx: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'csv'
invoking the NVIDIA Container Runtime Hook directly (e.g. specifying the docker --gpus flag) is not supported. Please use the NVIDIA Container Runtime instead.: unknown

Could anyone explain what this message mean exactly and what might the problem be? because I saw similar errors in different places

[some command result for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epXJ3.png)

[some command result for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LOHK.png)

[some command result for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGpZ6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  If you install the previous version, 1.9 it should work until they can fix 1.10.  For more information, check out this: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nvidia-container-runtime and read the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am wondering which software u meant by "the version 1.9".